# Code in C won't print out answers?

Tags: c

I am trying to input the value of x and a value for n for the number of terms to find the natural log using Taylor series and another series. The problem is is that my output is not showing up but just showing a blank space when I enter values. Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    double x = atof(argv[1]);
    double i;
    double y;
    double result2;
    double result;
    double error1; 
    double error2;
    double sum;
    int n = atof(argv[2]);

    if( x <= 0){
        printf("Invalid argument\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if(abs(x-1) <= 1 && abs(x-1) !=0){
        for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
            result -= pow((x-1), i )/ i;
        }
    }       
    else{
        for(i =1; i <=n; i--){
            result += 1/(i * pow((y),i));
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i <=n; i+=2){

        y = (x-1)/(x+1);
        sum += pow((y),i) * (1 / (1+i));
        result2 = sum * 2 * y;
    }


    error1 = result - log(x);
    error2 = result2 - log(x);

    printf("Taylor series: ln(%lf) ~= %lf\n", x, result);
    printf("    Error: %lf\n", error1);
    printf("Other series: ln(%lf) ~= %lf\n", x, result2);
    printf("    Error: %lf\n", error2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: n should be declared as a double, or use atoi()

Comment: `y`,`result`, `sum` uninitialize.

Comment: Seems hopeless, are you aware what you are doing? Try adding comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `y` without initializing it. Initialize it first before using it in the program.  Specifically this line

```
result += 1/(i * pow((y),i));
```

will try to use y when it is null.

Also the loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
```

is not that effective as it is iterating only once.